# Calculate row-wise dot products based on previous row and next row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
     Coordinate
1   (1150.0,1760.0)
28  (1260.0,1910.0)
6   (1030.0,2070.0)
12  (1170.0,2300.0)
9   (790.0,2260.0)
5   (750.0,2030.0)
26  (490.0,2130.0)
29  (360.0,1980.0)
3   (40.0,2090.0)
2   (630.0,1660.0)
20  (590.0,1390.0)
```

Now, I want to create a new column 'dotProduct' by applying the formula
`np.dot((b-a),(b-c))` where `b` is the Coordinates(1260.0,1910.0) for index 28, `c` is the same for index 6, (i.e. (1030.0,2070.0)). The calculated product is for row 2. So, in a way I have to get the previous row value and next value too. This way I have to calculate for entire 'Coordinate' I am quite new to pandas, hence still in learning path. Please guide me a bit.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, something like this: b=np.array([1260.0,1910.0])
a=np.array([1150.0, 1760.0])
c=([1030.0,2070.0])
print( np.dot((b-a),(b-c))) gives 1300.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `'Coordinate'` column elements are already tuples of float values.

```
# Convert elements of 'Coordinate' into numpy array
df.Coordinate = df.Coordinate.apply(np.array)

# Subtract +/- 1 shifted values from original 'Coordinate'
a = df.Coordinate - df.Coordinate.shift(1)
b = df.Coordinate - df.Coordinate.shift(-1)

# take row-wise dot product based on the arrays a, b
df['dotProduct'] = [np.dot(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]

# make 'Coordinate' tuple again (if you want)
df.Coordinate = df.Coordinate.apply(tuple)
```

Now I get this as `df`:

```
             Coordinate  dotProduct

1      (1150.0, 1760.0)         NaN
28     (1260.0, 1910.0)      1300.0
6      (1030.0, 2070.0)     -4600.0
12     (1170.0, 2300.0)     62400.0
9       (790.0, 2260.0)    -24400.0
5       (750.0, 2030.0)     12600.0
26      (490.0, 2130.0)    -18800.0
29      (360.0, 1980.0)    -25100.0
3        (40.0, 2090.0)    236100.0
2       (630.0, 1660.0)    -92500.0
20      (590.0, 1390.0)         NaN
```